# Download file on Form post without redirect

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I've got a Form which gets submitted to call a mvc controller action. The controller action returns a `FilePathResult`. The problem is that I don't want to redirct the page which contains the form. So is there any way to open a new tab, submit the page and close the tab?

Comment: Try adding `target="_new"` to your `<form>` tag in your HTML... not sure if that would work for you since there's little context here.

Comment: Why don't you just do a fileResult?

Comment: Thank you so much! Why don't you write that as an answer. It solved my problem. Just tried it with IE and Chrome(I would guess it should also work for other browsers). @HamzaKubba